# Proving a set of numbers are distinct

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive squarefree number. Prove that $0,1,b_1,\ldots,b_{n-2}$ are all distinct numbers where \begin{align*}0^m &\equiv 0 \pmod{n} \\1^m &\equiv 1 \pmod{n} \\2^m &\equiv b_1 \pmod{n} \\&\vdots\\(n-1)^m &\equiv b_{n-2} \pmod{n}\end{align*}  and $x^{t+1} \equiv x \pmod{n}$ with $m$ relatively prime to $t$ for positive integer $t$ and all integers $x$.

I wasn't sure how to use the given information to solve the question, but it seems like maybe using the pigeonhole principle or proof by contradiction may help. Also, the fact that $m$ is relatively prime to $t$ could be an indication to relate $t$ and $m$

Comment: If $n=6$ and $m=4$ then we have
$$0^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$$
$$1^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$$
$$2^4 \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$$
$$3^4 \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$$
$$4^4 \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$$
$$5^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$$

Did you mean to write "Prove that if ..."?

Comment: @rtybase This doesn't work since the period, $6$, isn't relatively prime to $4$.

Comment: If $n=9$ and $m=4$ then we have
$$0^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$$
$$1^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$
$$2^4 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$$
$$3^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$$
$$4^4 \equiv 4 \pmod{9}$$
$$5^4 \equiv 4 \pmod{9}$$
$$6^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$$
$$7^4 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$$
$$8^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$
?

Comment: @rtybase Hmm, that seems to work as $t = 9$?

Comment: One thing I know for sure is that $m$ can not be even, otherwise if $m=2q$ then from $$n-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$$ we have $$(n-1)^{2q} \equiv (-1)^{2q} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

Comment: So, I think this question needs a bit of polishing, a clear separation of what is given and what should be proved. Maybe few working examples.